# Device to prevent popping the circuit breaker if device draws too much power?

Tags: surge-protection

I just moved into my own office space and the outlets are shared across multiple offices on the same electrical line. I have a 2000-3000w reflow machine that I turn on occasionally which is connected to an 110v to a 220v upconverter.

In my previous space which I had my own breaker, I used to pop my circuit breaker many times because I forgot to turn off the hot air station before using the reflow machine. At this new space, I don't want to be a nuisance and pop the circuit breaker affecting everyone else.

What device or solution is there to just pop my room only? I know a surge protector might work, but how do you buy one that limits a certain amount of surge?

Comment: Use the same socket for both of them so you have to unplug one before plugging the other one in?

Comment: Talk to your landlord about having a dedicated power circuit installed.  It already sounds like your office is overloading one circuit.

Comment: Call maintenance and ask them to put in a separate line for the reflow machine. You have no way to control whatever the other people have powered up.

Comment: Don't know what kind of breakers you have, but if there are other offices connected to your line, even if you turn off your hot air station, there might be a problem? Here 16A are usually the max, so the oven alone would be borderline.

Comment: Surge proctector won't do it.  The proper part is a circuit breaker.  Or, put a child safety cover on one of the outlets so that you can't plug both devices in at once

Comment: A dedicated power circuit is an investment, but in a work environment it's probably an investment that makes financial sense. Compare the running cost of man-hours lost when the power goes out, and the running cost of man hours wasted on taking precautions so that the power won't go out, versus the one time cost of slapping a new cable on the wall.

Comment: @Dampmaskin not to mention the effects when your boss in the other room's PC suddenly goes out and he loses the report he just spent 4 hours working on.....

Comment: When you ask them get them to put in an appropriate 220V outlet too....

Comment: A *Device to prevent popping the circuit breaker if device draws too much* is a dedicated circuit.  You had a dedicated circuit breaker and you *pop my circuit breaker many times*.  This indicates the circuit breaker and wire were not properly sized for your use.  This is an indication you are doing something wrong.  Everytime a CB trips, you are putting stress on the CB and the wire.  Tell someone you need a dedicated circuit at 220V and rated current.  This is a basic electrical safety issue.

Comment: a circuit breaker _you_ add can't account for the _others_ in your office on the same branch, but it would protect against you using both the machine and hot air. a regular replacement circuit breaker from a big box store can do that.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you could even do this then you will **burn down the building** when the wire in the wall melts. You are pulling 27 A using 3kW on 110V using that machine alone.

Instead you should get a 240V line to your reflow machine. There is a reason high power devices are 240V, the required current is *halved* by doubling the voltage.

If you have a split-phase supply (where a neutral is shared between 2 opposing live phases) then you can pull the 240 V from that. However there are various regulatory restrictions on using a circuit like that. Talk to the owner of the place.

Comment: how would the wiring be exposed to 27A if circuit breakers limit outlet runs to 20A?

Comment: if it's actually 2kW then it's only 18 A (a bit more to account for the conversion loss)